# Previously working proxy request no longer working due to connection issues with server

Tags: mysql, eclipse, proxy

Here is the error message:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/auth/get from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

I've been working and testing a website by doing a proxy request. It was working (so the code should be correct), but after updating my mac O.S. to Sonoma over the weekend and coming back to my code, it stopped working and keeps giving me the ECONNREFUSED error.

On the Eclipse side, I get the following lines (and many more):

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
```

I've tried restarting my laptop, which usually solves the issue, but it didn't work.
I've also tried adding `"changeOrigin": true` which didn't work.

I forgot to mention this, but I am using angular and a java backend, if that changes anything.

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**
I've figured out that my server is working, and the issue is with the connection between the remote server with the MySQL and laptop. I can't update the config files for the remote server so I would need to change things on my end.

Comment: ECONNREFUSED suggests that there's nothing listening on the port you're trying to connect to. Are you sure your service is active?

Comment: My server is active -- the issue is in the connection, and I don't know why... The server is remote so I personally can't change anything in the config files or anything like that, so is there anything I can do on my laptop to get it working again?